# How get the return value of my block

Tags: objective-c

I have a variable that is a block type with Bool return and void params.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) BOOL (^shouldDisplayView)(void);
```

I implement this block in another class of mine

```
myClass.shouldDisplayView = ^BOOL(void) {
    return self->_count > 0;
};
```

I want to execute this block and check for the result, like:

```
if (result of shouldDisplayView is true) ...
```

Is it simply

```
if (shouldDisplayView)
```

or is this checking if it's non-null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (myClass.shouldDisplayView)`

will check `shouldDisplayView` isn't `nil`.

If you want to check result of `shouldDisplayView` is `true`, it should be

`if (myClass.shouldDisplayView && myClass.shouldDisplayView())`

Comment: self.shouldDisplayView() is giving me an error. My code is obj-c

Comment: What is the error? I checked my code before uploading it and it works normally

Comment: Called object type BOOL is not a function or function pointer

Comment: I checked again and it works without any errors. Please add your code to the question or you can check my code in a new project.

Comment: Sorry, I had two very similar variable names, fixed it